# Sync subtitle with the movie using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, iframe

I'm trying to sync my subtitle with an iframe video from YouTube.
Please note that I'm not using common subtitle formats like vtt and srt, I want to write it in JSON.

My main question is how can I sync my JSON file with this iframe video in the correct timestamps?
example of my json subtitle :

```
{ "id": 10, "transcript": "sample text", "time-in": "0.6", "time-out": "3.5"}
```

I also want the subtitle to be displayed under the video in a separate div.

And this picture shows what I exactly want it to look like :
 [click here to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qfkb.jpg)

I would appreciate it if you share your ideas on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the current time with the youtube iframe api.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

So you can to poll the current time with an interval.

```
setInterval(() => player.getCurrentTime());
```